# is my url hash defined as jquery data?

Tags: jquery

I am triggering a javascript based on a hash passed in a url.

But if the hash is not one that I am expecting I don't want to trigger.

The list of expected hashes is defined using the `data-category` attribute.

How could I get an array of this data so I can see if my hash is in the array?

Here is the HTML I am given:

```
    <div class="filter_padder" id="nav_channels">
        <div class="filter_wrapper" style="max-width:650px;">
            <div class="filter selected" data-category="cat-all">ALL</div>
            <div class="filter" data-category="MusicWorld">MusicWorld</div>
            <div class="filter" data-category="Awards">Awards</div>
            <div class="filter" data-category="MX">Exchange</div>
            <div class="filter last-child" data-category="Com">Community</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
// set any hash in the url to a variable
var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');

// see if my hash is expected (would like to handle this dynamically)
if(hash === (cat_all|Awards|MX|Com)) {
  doSomething();
}
```

But I don't know how to dynamically build the list of elements to compare to 'hash'.  I think it's something along the lines of:

```
$('#nav_channels').data('category');
```

But can't get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
if( $('.filter[data-category="'+hash+'"]').length ) { 
  doSomething();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values into an array like so:

```
var cats = $('[data-category]').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('category');
}).get();
```